# What's the meaning of "the least" in these sentences?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I like her the least.

> It's the least expensive device available.

As far as I know, the first sentence means that I dislike her. Is it right?
The second sentence means it's the smallest expensive device available. Is it right?

I'm not sure whether I grasp the meaning of *the least*.

Comment: We expect people to do a little research before asking a question, In this case, you could look at the meanings and examples of **least** in a good dictionary like this one: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/least . If, after your research, you are still unsure, please edit your question to add details of your research, including links, and explain what exactly you are still unsure about.

Answer (score 6):

"The least" is just a measure of less than the others.

Like A < B.  A < C.  A < D...

The first sentence does not necessarily mean you dislike her.  Maybe you like everyone else very much, and of all the people you like, you like her the least.

In the second sentence, the device may be expensive, but it is cheaper than the other options.

Comment: Good answer! I think it's worth noting that, without additional context, these examples don't really make any implication either way. "It's the least expensive device available" for instance might mean it's really cheap, or it might, as you suggest here, still be expensive but just less expensive than all the others - or anywhere in between those two. You'd need more context to know for sure.